# Swift Generics: Explicitly declared parameter Set<UUID> converts to CVarArg but generic Set<S> with UUID's does not

Tags: ios, swift, generics, uuid, nspredicate

I'm building a generic Realm Swift query function. I started by getting it to work with everything declared explicitly. Now I'm moving parameters into generic types.

This is my function and it works like this:

```
func queryFromCollection<T: Object>(of type: T.Type, query set: Set<UUID>, for key: String) async -> Results<T>? {

    let objects = await RealmReadService.instance.readObjects(of: type)

    var predicates: [NSPredicate] = []
    for item in set {
        let query = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", key, item as CVarArg)
        predicates.append(query)
    }
    let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(orPredicateWithSubpredicates: predicates)
    
    return objects!.filter(compoundPredicate)
}
```

The `Set` of `UUID`s converts to `CVarArg` just fine.

Now, when I use this code to make my `Set` generic:

```
func queryFromCollection<T: Object, S>(of type: T.Type, query set: Set<S>, for key: String) async -> Results<T>?
```

and in my loop I have to change `item as! CVarArg`. This compiles and runs until I do the query.

Once I run the query it fails and I get this: "Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.UUID' (0x1df22b1e0) to 'Swift.CVarArg' (0x13b14e7b8)"

I'm struggling to understand why it can convert `UUID`s to `CVarArg` when the `Set` is declared as a `Set<UUID>` but not with a generic `Set`.

Comment: You have not put any constraints on the set element type, `S`, but not every type can be converted to  `CVarArg`.

Comment: `let query = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [key, item])` should be a working solution. As why exactly it fails on your case, I'd say that @Sweeper answer is correct about why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because `UUID` is bridged to `NSUUID` in the case of `Set<UUID>`. `NSUUID` inherits `NSObject`, which *does* implement `CVarArg`.

However, in the generic case, this bridging does not happen, because it is not necessarily the case that the generic type can be bridged.

Other than making your function only take `CVarArg`s,

```
func queryFromCollection<T: Object, S: NSObject>(of type: T.Type, query set: Set<S>, for key: String) async -> Results<T>?
```

which would require the caller to do a lot of explicit conversion to `NSUUID`, I can only think of one other rather ugly way - make a `CVarArgConvertible` protocol

```
protocol CVarArgConvertible {
    func toCVarArg() -> CVarArg
}

extension UUID: CVarArgConvertible {
    func toCVarArg() -> CVarArg {
        self as NSUUID
    }
}

// other bridgable types you want to use...
```

Then `queryFromCollection` would look like:

```
func queryFromCollection<T: Object, S: CVarArgConvertible>(of type: T.Type, query set: Set<S>, for key: String) async -> Results<T>? {
    // in here you would call "toCVarArg" on an element of the set to get a CVarArg.
}
```

Or, as [Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) reminded me in the comments, you can use the other overload of `NSPredicate`, that doesn't take `CVarArg`s, but an `[Any]?` instead:

```
let query = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [key, item])
```

Comment: While I think the bridge NSUUID/UUID indeed explains the issue, a quicker solution without having all that overwork you did would be to use `let query = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [key, item])`, which seems to be worrking (at least, it doesn't crash, and seems to work. Sample test: https://pastebin.com/6A80asMQ (I modify a little to rermove dependency on Realm, and used a Codable for the example instead.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for reminding me. I was too tunnel visioned into getting a `CVarArg` and forgot what OP was actually trying to do :)

Comment: Yeah, argumentArray [key, item] worked. Thanks!